# CassandraOperations update record error: PRIMARY KEY part id found in SET part

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I know Cassandra does not allow primary key update, so I have problem with my code below:

```
final CassandraBatchOperations batchOps = cassandraOperations.batchOps();
batchOps.update(myEntity).execute();
```

So I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part id found in SET part
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:295)
    ... 65 more
```

The [Datastax driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) says that I should avoid passing my primary key on my set list, so far so good if I do an update manually I can avoid this problem. But how to avoid this error using the CassandraBatchOperations from spring-data?

Comment: Care to post your table description and your entity class code (fields/properties, no getters/setters/… required here)?

Comment: I ran into this issue using the java-driver, particularly the [mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/mapper/#mapper). I don't know if Spring uses Mapper under the hood or not, but if it does, I ran into this issue when doing an update and forgetting to set the primary key on this record when calling `dao.update(record)` (assuming `record` is an instance of your [entity class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/mapper/#entity-class), `dao` is an interface annotated with @dao and you have a `update` method defined on your dao interface).